# Recurring decimals to fraction

Tags: fractions

1. $.\overline{36}=\frac{36}{99}$
2. $2.1\overline{36}=2\frac3{22}$

The part I do not understand however, is "you could used 1) to speed up the working of 2)" which is written in the book.

How would I use 1) to help me work out 2)?

Thanks.

Comment: $\frac3{22}=.1\overline{36}\text{ not } .1\overline{39}$

Comment: my bad, both were .36 not .39.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2.1\overline{39}=2+0.1+\frac1{10}\cdot0.\overline{39}$$

So, $$2.1\overline{39}=2+\frac1{10}+\frac1{10}\cdot\frac{36}{99}=2+\frac1{10}\cdot\left(1+\frac4{11}\right)=2+\frac1{10}\cdot\frac{15}{11}=2+\frac3{22}$$

Comment: I've probably missed something here, but would that not = 2.239?

Comment: @user2121482, please find the edited answer

Comment: thanks. really confused at first (for example where the 4/11 came from), however it was my own bad since i had confused .39 with .36.

Comment: how did you get 15/11?

Comment: @user2121482, $$1+\frac4{11}=\frac{11+4}{11}=\frac{15}{11}$$ and cancelling out $9$ from the numerator & the denominator, $$\frac{36}{99}=\frac4{11}$$

Comment: Thank you. I thought you'd done something else. I assume the way I did it, getting 2 + 1/10 + 2/55 is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

1. $.\overline{36}=\frac{36}{99}$
2. $2.1\overline{36}=2\frac3{22}$

## part 1.

suppose
$$\begin {equation}\dfrac pq=0.\overline{36}\end {equation}$$
this is eqn (1).

mulipltly this eqn with 100
$$\begin {equation}100\dfrac pq=36.\overline{36}\end {equation}$$
this is eqn (2).Now subtract (1) from (2).
$$\begin {equation}100\dfrac pq-\frac pq=36.\overline{36}-0.\overline{36}\end {equation}$$
$$99\dfrac pq=36.0$$
$$\dfrac pq=\frac {36}{99}$$

## part 2

$2.1\overline{36}=2+0.1\overline{36}$
$$\dfrac pq=0.1\overline{36}\implies 10\dfrac pq=1.\overline{36}$$this is eqn (1).

multilpy with 100 in eqn(1)
$$1000\dfrac pq=136.\overline{36}$$ then subtract (1)  from (2).
$$990\dfrac pq=135.0$$
$$\dfrac pq=\dfrac {135}{990}\implies\dfrac {3}{22}$$

so  $2.1\overline{36}\implies 2+0.1\overline{36}\implies 2+\dfrac{3}{22}\implies 2\dfrac3{22}$